# How to restore Oracle 19c after Windows reinstall

Tags: oracle

I had to reinstall Windows 10 on my home PC but I still have all the Oracle folders:

- Oracle Base
- Oracle Software
- Oracle Data

I'd like to restore the entire database (schemas: users, tablespaces...)

Could someone provide a guide what steps I need to carry out?

Thanks

Comment: Use  [oradim](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ntqrf/creating-an-instance-using-oradim.html) utility to create instance and 'netca' for listener

Comment: Another option create services manually with `sc create service`.I found [this](http://linuxtechres.blogspot.com/2011/10/how-to-create-oracle-database-service.html) that shows both options.